# codeigniter write htaccess inside application

Tags: php, .htaccess, upload, codeigniter-2

Can we write an .htaccess file inside CI's application folder to increase limit of upload_max_filesize.

I have tried with creating .htaccess file inside application folder but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure that your php.ini is set to the correct upload_max_filesize also.

To note, you can have multiple .htaccess files inside of a project folder directory, so another .htaccess file might also be affecting you.

Try going with something like this: 
http://www.miscdebris.net/blog/2008/04/14/changing-the-php-file-upload-limit-in-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Steven, Thanks for you response. I am working in my local setup with Codeigniter installed. My main concern is like differnt moduled in the my views should need to have different upload limits from server level. I tried with multiple htaccess without using CI framework. It works fine. But while using with frame work inside application folder it is not working.

Comment: @Pushkar In that case, I would set a site-wide upload limit of .htaccess or php.ini to the highest level, and then adjust the upload limit to lower levels with your upload script, per page

Answer (score 0):

The *upload_max_filesize* is actually a PHP configuration and not Apache or what ever web server you are using. This means you can't set that through *.htaccess* because this is a server configuration, kind of extension.

Where as ***upload_max_filesize*** is set inside php.ini.

- If you have access to your host shell, then you can find it usually at: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, as most topics suggest, but it depend on the configuration.
- You can also have multiple php.ini configuration files. Some hosting companies provide additional one inside your project main directory, giving you the ability to set project depended PHP configurations, as the one you desire from there.
  Of course, if you have shell access to your hosting and root privileges you can do that your self by using *Apache Virtual host* configuration setup to define a new php.ini extension. Here is a short article I found useful: [How to specify a custom php.ini](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php).
- If you are on a shared host and have CPanel or other panel access, some of them expose PHP configurations through UI, so you could check that option too.
- Of course you can also try using the php internal function: [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set), like that: `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');` to set needed limit directly in the code and for the script which needs that instead for the whole project.
  In order to supply it for the whole application then do that at your "index.php" file, the one which loads first and always.
  ** Before using this option, make sure, **ini_set** is enabled at your host, just change a value before you call *phpinfo()* and check if it is changed, you can also check the php *disable_functions* flag in php.ini.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Svetoslav Dragoev. As I am working on my local machine I do have access to Apache. "ini_set" will not work inside scripts as "upload_max_filesize" is a PerDir mode. I tried creating custom php.ini where it blocked wthile restarting the Apache with below issue:

Comment: 3:15:31 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:15:31 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:15:31 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:15:31 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:15:31 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:15:31 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
3:15:31 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

Comment: Hi Pushkar,
Sorry for my late reply, on the error you receive, unfortunately I can't really help without knowing your exact configuration and being able to check your configuration files and setup, even OS type and versions are important.

If you are using your local machine, then why don't you just change your original PHP ini file or you want that change only for a specific project?

Another probably quite easy solution, depending on your dev environment is to setup a Docker or Vagrant, there you can define what ever PHP configuration you like?